# Considering Using Firebase

Tags: firebase

We are considering using firebase for building an emailing tool. Before starting to using this tool I would like to ask a question:

In a traditional database we first create the DB, create the tables and the constraints. etc. before starting to use the DB. How do you achieve this in firebase?

Is there a console to use to start a new database(reference)? Do you do that by script that you run each time the you need to make changes?

Where to keep the scripts? Do you keep then in your project and run them as need be or always at start up?

What is the general approach???

Do you make a separate project that manages the data structure in firebase and then just consume the data structure from other projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase is a schema-less data store, which means you don't have to create tables, constraints or any of that stuff. You sign up and create a Firebase, and start writing data, that's it.

You can use the Firebase security rules to enforce some aspects of the schema and to make sure users only write to locations they're allowed to.

For the final question, I recommend checking out this blog post for details on where Firebase can fit in your app: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-03-25-where-does-firebase-fit.html - it's possible to use Firebase as the complete backend for your app, or only just a portion. That choice will dictate which pieces of code (server or client) will talk to Firebase.